How to convert my Flutter project into an apk file
I have built a simple Flutter SMS reporting system but I am facing a challenge to convert my project into an APK file format.
I have tried the CMD prompt to converting a Flutter project into an APK file but I think my setup has a Gradle problem and therefore fails to convert file.
I have tried using the CMD approach:

flutter build apk

flutter build apk --release


But after I run the command I have an error message saying:
Microsoft Windows \[Version 10.0.22631.4249\]

(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

F:\\CurrentSMSAPP\\electionresults_results_sms_collation_mobileapp\>flutter build apk

 Building with sound null safety 

/main.dart: Error: Error when reading '/main.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

package:electionresults_results_sms_collation_mobileapp//main.dart: Error: No 'main' method found.

Try adding a method named 'main' to your program.

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

\* Where:

Script 'D:\\installed\\flutter\\packages\\flutter_tools\\gradle\\flutter.gradle' line: 1151

\* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

\\> Process 'command 'D:\\installed\\flutter\\bin\\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

\* Try:

\\> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

\\> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

\\> Run with --scan to get full insights.

\* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           38.5s

Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

F:\\CurrentSMSAPP\\electionresults_results_sms_collation_mobileapp\>


I don't use flutter, but the error is complaining about main.dart.  Does that file exist?  And you should [edit] your question with any build/configuration files that a flutter dev will need to provide actual help.

Does the project build and run successfully? It looks like you have build errors. Logs say it can not find main.dart. Make sure it's in  project_directory/lib/main.dart.
Also you should run flutter build apk command where pubspec.yaml file lives.
If you do everything correct and can't solve the issue, try running flutter clean and then build again.

For the final release you can use the following command to generate APK or appbundle for release.
Appbundle:
flutter build appbundle --no-tree-shake-icons --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --release

APK:
flutter build apk --no-tree-shake-icons --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --release

